# How to re-determine column type in Stata

Tags: stata

I had a column of numbers in Stata that was however read in as strings because it contained a string value "nan" for one of the numbers. I have since replaced this with a missing value, so that the column only contains numbers now, albeit all in string format. What is the command to re-determine the type of the column?

Comment: Good questions here show some attempt at code and (for this kind of query) show data examples. Much of the advice at http://www.statalist.org/forums/help is pertinent, especially using `dataex` (SSC) to give a data example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminology: "columns" in Stata are always called **variables**.

Variables being numeric or string is in the first instance a matter of **variable type** or storage type. Display format is then to be assigned. "Format" in Stata doesn't mean variable type.

With data like this

```
clear
input str5 stryit 
"1"
"2"
"42"
"666"
"NAN"
end
```

There are several prudent rules.

Check to see what kinds of observations wouldn't produce numeric values if coerced:

```
tab stryit if missing(real(stryit))
```

If there are many such kinds, you might need to rethink the approach.

Always leave the original variable as it came unless and until you are sure that you no longer need it. So use `destring` with `force` if you like but `generate` a new variable. In your case that would be fine.

```
destring stryit, force gen(ntryit1)
```

Better than using `force` is to be explicit about your conversion rules. That leaves a record of what you did (assuming naturally that you keep a record of all commands used in any serious analysis):

```
destring stryit, ignore("NA") gen(ntryit2)
```

You can explicitly change problematic values before `destring`. An advantage of that, like the previous rule, is that you have a record of what you did.

```
clonevar stryit2 = stryit 
replace stryit2 = "." if stryit2 == "NAN"` 
destring stryit2, gen(ntryit3)
```

Check to see that results make sense:

```
list 


     +------------------------------------------------+
     | stryit   ntryit2   ntryit1   stryit2   ntryit3 |
     |------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      1         1         1         1         1 |
  2. |      2         2         2         2         2 |
  3. |     42        42        42        42        42 |
  4. |    666       666       666       666       666 |
  5. |    NAN         .         .         .         . |
     +------------------------------------------------+
```

Disclaimer: original author of `destring`